# How to make form with two vertical columns of inputs

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to make a page with two columns of input forms.

For example texboxes on left and checkboxes on the right.

How could I do this

```
#left
{
  float:left;


}

#right
{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted so far. Generally at StackOverflow, people don't give code unless an attempt is proven.

Comment: Agreed - not enough detail. Assemble a mockup and ask a more specific question: http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: there is css that is better then nothing... the question is fine

Comment: I don't agree that there isn't enough detail.  This is a simple enough question, and a common one too.  Maybe the fact that he wants to make "a form" is a bit of a herring, but the essence is he wants two divs laid out in column format.  I landed here from a Google search and my question was answered exactly.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kFcDE/7/

HTML:

```
<!-- HTML with text on left, and check boxes on right -->
<div>
  <form method="post" action="url/to/your/server/here">

    <!-- First float left -->
    <div class="float-left t-area-wrapper">
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Second float left -->
    <div class="float-left c-box-wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" name="box1"></input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box2"></input>
    </div>

    <!-- Clear - notice this is a sibling of the els with floats -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>
</div>


<!-- HTML with check boxes on LEFT, and text on RIGHT -->
<div>
  <form method="post" action="url/to/your/server/here">

    <!-- FIRST float left -->
    <div class="float-left c-box-wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" name="box1"></input>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box2"></input>
    </div>


    <!-- SECOND float left -->
    <div class="float-left t-area-wrapper">
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Clear - notice this is a sibling of the els with floats -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Use this class for borders/padding/etc to 
    position the text elements way you like */
.t-area-wrapper {

}

/* Use this class for borders/padding/etc to
   position the checkboxes the way you like */    
.c-box-wrapper {

}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Don't forget to add a clear div as the last sibling of floated elements when using float....

Comment: Excellent and flexible answer that doesn't rely on setting widths or heights.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two divs. One with the style:

```
.left_div_input_boxes {

width:50%;
float:left;

}
```

And one with

```
.right_div_check_boxes {

    width:50%;
    float:right;

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z7bQ6/

Comment: Can I make it so there are two columns of checboxes on left side to side? So 3 columns all together.

Answer (score 0):

Inputs are inline elements, so they will stay side-by-side unless you insert a break or block-level element:

```
<input type="text" /><input type="checkbox"><br /><input type="text" /><input type="checkbox">
```

This will produce two columns of inputs, with no styling needed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of each column (#left and #right) to 49%. This will make them each take up half the screen, with a little spacing in the middle. (Also, if both are set to 50%, you can have rounding issues that bump one of the columns down below the other.